# Can't pass a single parameter to lambda function in MVVM Light Toolkit's RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I don't know if there's a difference between Josh Smith's and Laurent Bugnion's implementations of RelayCommand or not, but everywhere I've looked, it sounds like the Execute portion of RelayCommand can take 0 or 1 parameters.  I've only been able to get it to work with 0.  When I try something like:

```
public class Test
{
    public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand((param) => SomeFunc(param));
    }

    private void SomeFunc( object param)
    {
    }
}
```

I get the error: `Delegate 'System.Action' does not take '1' arguments`.  Just to make sure I am not insane, I went to the definition of RelayCommand to make sure I didn't have some rogue implementation in my solution somewhere, but sure enough, it was just Action, and not Action<>.

What on earth am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CanExecute on RelayCommand<T> not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306063/canexecute-on-relaycommandt-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The non-generic implementation of `RelayCommand` (in MVVM Light) does not accept a parameter. Use `RelayCommand<Object>` instead, or (even better) `RelayCommand<YourCustomType>` so the parameter to `SomeFunc` is strongly typed.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, I *finally* also found that info on a somewhat related post (slaps forehead) -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306063/canexecute-on-relaycommandt-not-working.  I was going to delete my question, but you were way too fast with your answer.  :)  I will accept this as soon as the system allows it!  Thank you.

Comment: I'll vote to close this one as a duplicate. We'll see which happens first. :)

Comment: Hee hee. We both won, in a way! :)