# "specified cast is not valid" GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)

Tags: c#, exception, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm pretty new to using MVVM Light so hopefully this is a simple fix, although I have spent most of the day trying to track down an answer :-(

In my xaml

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="m_dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" >

.
.
.

<Button x:Name="cmdFTSViewText" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="5"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="View Text">
  <Image Source="../Images/ViewDocumentText.png" Stretch="None"/>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=FindModel.ViewDocumentTextCommand}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding iUniqueID}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

In my ViewModel

```
public RelayCommand<int> ViewDocumentTextCommand { get; private set; }
public FindModel() 
{
    .
    .
    .
    ViewDocumentTextCommand = new RelayCommand<Int32>(p => { ViewDocumentText(p); });
}

public void ViewDocumentText(Int32 iDocumentID)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

SearchResults.iUniqueID is an Int32

For some reason this is throwing the above exception when the button is pressed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CanExecute on RelayCommand<T> not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306063/canexecute-on-relaycommandt-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's because your RelayCommand is defined as a `RelayCommand<int>` and you're trying to assign a `RelayCommand<Int32>` to it

Try changing your command definition to a simple `ICommand` instead.

It could also be that the value is null prior to the initial binding. Try using an object instead and not specifying the type.

`new RelayCommand(p => ViewDocumentText(p));`

and

`public void ViewDocumentText(object iDocumentID)`

Comment: thanks for the pointers.  The <int> / <Int32> wasn't the problem.  That was just my mistake in reporting the issue.  I'd been trying both variants to diagnose the problem and forget to press Undo 1 more time before posting :$

Substituting in

Comment: Substituting in

    ViewDocumentTextCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(p => { ViewDocumentText(p); });

got the code working and allowed me to diagnose the issue though :-)

Turns out that my Int32 is ending up as a string in the xaml. Which I'm now thinking has something to do with the GetBindableData member of the Silverlight.DataSet.DataView object.Thanks again.

Comment: Strings in XAML are not automatically converted properly, this is in fact quite tricky to get right. I am planning to try and make it better in a future version of MVVM Light, but it is not very easy. Cheers!

Comment: I had this issue, one viewmodel worked, the other threw the "specified cast is invalid" exception... I tracked it down to this" the working viewmodel was "using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;" the one that did not work was "using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;" (missing "Wpf")....